# In Django, how to save an object only if a field has a known value

Tags: django, orm

In Django, I would like to do a save of an object only if a given field has a known value, otherwise I would like to get an exception.

Is there some other way then doing it manually, locking the table (or row, with Django 1.4 SELECT FOR UPDATE support) before saving, reading the value, checking, and if they match, saving, otherwise throwing an exception?

In SQL I could do something like:

```
UPDATE table SET field='value' WHERE id=42 AND given_field='known_value'
```

and checking how many rows were updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can place your validation code in `save` method, for example.

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class YourModel(models.Model):
    # fields

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.given_field == 'known_value':
            raise ValidationError(u"You can't do that!")
        super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The only things here is that 1) you won't get this validation if using bulk update and 2) this validation will break in admin

(2) is solved if you move your validation to model's clean method.

Comment: No, this does not work. I would have to reread `self` from the database first to see if it is really `'known_value'` there. And while I am doing that, I would also have to lock the table/row to be sure somebody does not change the values between the check and the update.

Answer (score 0):

Use queryset's `update()` method:

```
obj_data = dict((field.name, getattr(obj, field.name))
                    for field in obj._meta.fields)

rows_affected = MyModel.objects.filter(
                   id=obj.id, given_field='known_value').update(**obj_data)
```

Comment: The idea is that I do not know what all has changed in the object between it was fetched from the database and place where I call `save`. So in ORM manner: I have retrieved an object, I played with it and now I want to call `save`, but I want to be sure that `save` succeeds only if one special field has a known value. If somebody else has changed this value in meantime, I would like an exception. So above mentioned `field='value'` is automatically done by Django.

Comment: Hm, why I have a feeling this would break with some m2m fields and other special fields? I am not sure if Django's `save` method is so simple as such an `update`.

Comment: You can add saving of m2m fields in case if `rows_affected` is non-zero.  Also you can manually fire `pre_save`/`post_save` signals if needed.

Comment: Thus reimplementing the wheel of existing `save` implementation. Not good.